# Variable might not have been initialized. What is the best way to solve that?

Tags: java

When I declare a double var do I need to address a value to each one all the time? I am asking that because I am trying to run the code below without adding any value to the double var but it says that the variable was not initialized. It works when I add the value 0 to each variable. So do I have to add values all the time to these variable or not?

```
    public static double taxSingleCalculation (){

    double taxbracket1 = 0, taxbracket2 = 0, taxbracket3 = 0, taxbracket4 = 0, taxbracket5 = 0, taxbracket6 = 0,taxbracket7 = 0;

        if (income <=9950) {
            taxbracket1 = income * taxRate10;
        }
        else{
            taxbracket1 = 9950*taxRate10;
        }
```

The compile error is the following:

```
C:\Users\src\estimation.java:97:35
java: variable taxbracket2 might not have been initialized
```

Comment: Strange....It is clearly shown in your code that `taxbracket2` is initialized with `0`. You would only get this error where you try to use this variable. It may be helpful to see that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting "variable taxbracket2 might not have been initialized" is that you used `textbracket2` somewhere in the unseen part of the code of the `taxSingleCalculation` method.  Every variable you declare must have been **definitely assigned** a value prior to being used.

There are a few options to solve this issue:

1. If it's convenient, temporarily comment-out the code that's using the unassigned variables;
2. Just go ahead and add the code which assigns the variables their "proper" values (which you were going to do *eventually* anyway, right?);
3. Do exactly what you did: assign a reasonable "dummy" initial value (such as zero) to each variable in the declaration, with the understanding that this dummy value will eventually be replaced by the appropriate "real" value.

As for the **best** way: I would, personally, vote for #2 (no time like the present, eh?), but it's entirely up to you.

Comment: Yep. I will go for your number 2 solution because it seems to be the fastest way to solve that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan on using the primitive variables in the code, then yes, you need to initialize them.

Note: Use an array instead of "numbered variables"

Comment: Very interesting. I will try that. Thank you